# I am writing a Standard ML function that inputs the name of a file and output will be the sum of the integers in that file returned. Ex. "input.txt"

Tags: smlnj

```
fun toInt(s) = valOf(Int.fromString s);  

fun sum([]) = 0
    | sum(x::xs) = toInt(x)+sum(xs);
```

-Which prints as follow:

`val toInt = fn : string -> int`
`val sum = fn : string list -> int`
`val it = () : unit`

-I am new on SML environment and I don't know how to get output of the sum in that type.

`fn : string -> int`

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: Error says operator and operand do not agree operator domain : string list, operand: string, in expression: sum "input.txt"

Comment: Duh, it's been a while since I used ML, but I think you should be doing something about "tail" and "rest of the list", but I see only one of them in your expression.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `sum "input.txt"` to work, you'll need to open the file and read the integers from it.

Here's a function to parse a list of integers from a character stream:

```ml
fun intListParser getc = ParserComb.zeroOrMore(Int.scan StringCvt.DEC) getc
```

The [ParserComb](http://smlnj.org/doc/smlnj-lib/Util/str-ParserComb.html) structure is from the SML/NJ library, which should be available automatically if you're using SML/NJ.

Here's the `sum` function. You can use `foldl` instead of writing a recursive function.

```ml
fun sum fname = let
      val file = TextIO.openIn fname
      val ints = valOf(TextIO.scanStream intListParser file)
       in TextIO.closeIn file;
          foldl op+ 0 ints
      end
```